# Как изменить значение при выборе определённого select'a и input'a

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток, только начал знакомство с javascript, делаю калькулятор, возникла такая сложность.

1) Есть select с видами материала(сталь,медь,титан,латунь)

```
<select id="material">
<option value="steelblack">Чёрная сталь</option>>
<option value="med">Медь</option>
<option value="titan">Титан</option>
<option value="lat">Латунь</option>
.........
</select>
```

2) Есть поле Input'ов для ввода значений

```
<label>
<div style="position: relative;">
Укажите длину (мм): <input type="text" id="b" value="0" />
Укажите ширину (мм):<input type="text" id="a" value="0" />
Укажите толщину (мм): <input type="text" name="h" id="h" value="0"  />
Укажите кол-во отверстий: <input type="text" id="hole" value="0">
Укажите длину реза (мм): <input type="text" id="cut" value="0">
Укажите кол-во гибов: <input type="text" id="gib" value="0"></br>
Укажите длину сварки (мм): <input type="text" id="svarka" value="0">
Укажите кол-во деталей: <input type="text" id="detail" value="0">
</label>
```

3) вывод информации на странице

```
    <div id="S"></div>
    <div id="S1"></div>
    <div id="m"></div>
    <div id="value"></div>
    <div id="t1"></div>
    <div id="price"></div>
<button onClick="calculate();">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
```

4) js файл

```
function calculate() {
    var material = document.getElementById('material').value;
    switch (material) {
        case "steelblack":
          cost = 51;  //стоимость железа, нужна для расчёта стоимости металла
          p = 7800   //плотность железа так же нужна для расчёта стоимости металла
          break
          case "steelos":
          cost = 66;
          p = 7800
          break
.......
    }
    var a  = document.getElementById('a').value;
    var b  = document.getElementById('b').value;
    var h  = document.getElementById('h').value;
    var hole  = document.getElementById('hole').value;
    var cut  = document.getElementById('cut').value;
    var gib  = document.getElementById('gib').value;
    var svarka  = document.getElementById('svarka').value;
    var detail = document.getElementById('detail').value;

    //подсчёты и вывод результатов
    var S = (a * b).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('S').innerHTML = "Площадь детали: "+ S +" мм2.";
    var S1 = (parseFloat (a) + parseFloat (b))*2;
    document.getElementById('S1').innerHTML = "Периметр: "+ S1 +" мм.";
    var v = parseFloat (S)* parseFloat (h);
    var m = (parseFloat (p)* parseFloat (v) /1000000000).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('m').innerHTML = "Масса: "+ m +" кг";
    var value = (parseFloat (m)* parseFloat (cost)).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "Стоимость металла: "+ value +" р.";
    var hole = parseFloat (hole)*10;
    document.getElementById('hole').innerHTML = "Стоимость дырок: "+ hole +" р.";
    var cut = parseFloat ((cut)*50)/1000;
    document.getElementById('cut').innerHTML = "Стоимость реза: "+ cut +" р.";
    var svarka = parseFloat ((svarka)*60)/1000;
    document.getElementById('svarka').innerHTML = "Стоимость сварки: "+ svarka +" р.";
    var gib = parseFloat (gib)*30;
    document.getElementById('gib').innerHTML = "Стоимость гибов: "+ gib +" р.";
    var t1 = (parseFloat (value)+ parseFloat (hole)+ parseFloat (cut)+ parseFloat (gib)+ parseFloat (svarka)).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML = "Общая стоимость одной детали: "+ t1 +" р.";
    var price = (t1 * detail).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = "Стоимость нескольких деталей: "+ price +" р.";
    }
    }
```

Сейчас цена на резку общая и считается так

var cutp = parseFloat ((cut)*50)/1000;

то есть просто берётся значение из input'a умножается на 50 и делиться на 1000

Задача стоит такая, необходимо сделать так чтобы менялось значение цены резки при выборе определённого металла и толщины этого металла

Необходимо следующие, когда выбирается металл (в массиве material) и указывается его толщина (в инпуте h) и исходя из этих данных автоматический выставляется цена для резки (инпут cut), ценники как я думаю можно забить в массив как пример

```
var cutPr
    switch (CutPr) {
        case "steel-05":
          Price = 3.80;
          thicknes = 0.5
          break

          case "steel-07":
          Price = 4.45;
          thicknes = 0.7
          break
```

грубо говоря, я выбираю медь(med), выставляю толщину(h) 1мм, у меня берётся цена за резку(cut) металла 3.80руб, в input'e **cut** вводится длина резки допустим 750мм, тут то и происходит расчёт 3.80/1000*cut = 2.85р за 750мм резки.

значение cut, должно браться из массива, исходя от выбранного металла в селекте и выставленного значения толщины

Comment: а проблема то  в чем состоит? что-то не работает, или вы что-то не понимаете? что именно?

Comment: не понимаю как вообще это реализовать, чтобы при выборе материала и выставление толщины менялся ценник на резку

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо повесить событие onchange на input и select:

```
<select id="material" onchange={yourFunc()}>
........
<input type="text" name="h" id="h" value="0" onchange={yourFunc()} />
```

Создаете в DOM дереве элемент чтобы выводить результат, например:

```
<p id="result"></p>
```

И создать функцию для подсчета цены:

```
function yourFunc() {
    // Берем значение из select
    var material = document.getElementById('material').value
    // Берем значение из input
    var input = document.getElementById('h').value
    var cost, p
    switch (material) {
       case "steelblack":
          cost = 51;
          p = 7800
          break
       ...
    }

    // На этом этапе у вас есть толщина, стоимость и плотность металла
    // Тут делаете какие то операции
    var result = ...
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result
}
```

Если нужно чтобы при загрузке уже цена отображалась, то добавьте во внутрь тега script

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", yourFunc);
```

Comment: попробовал совместить ваше со своим и всё уходит в ошибку NaN, так же как я понимаю у вас расчёт идёт из cost, а мне нужно чтобы расчёт производился совершенно с другого блока, допустим сделать переменную var cutprice и туда case sb0.5 = 12; sb0.7 = 16, то есть нужно чтобы был определён какой метал выбран и какая толщина и исходя из этих данный с другого места бралась цена для расчёта стоимости резки

Comment: @st1mset этого не было в условии:) сделайте какой нибудь массив с объектами: var costs = [{'0.5' : 12}, {'0.7': 16}, ...]. У вас есть значение инпута: var input = document.getElementById('h').value. Можете получить цену: costs[input], где input это толщина.

Comment: да я просто выразился не правильно изначально, попробую сейчас разобраться с той информацией что вы мне дали)

Comment: А не подскажите еще как разделить цены можно? типов материала много и разный ценник на резку у них, делать под каждый свой массив?

Comment: Думаю да, какого то универсального способа не вижу к сожалению:(

Answer (score 1):

```js
const MATERIALS = {
  steelblack: { cost: 51, p: 7800 }, 
  steelos   : { cost: 66, p: 7800 }, 
  med       : { cost: 23.2, p: 0 }, 
  titan     : { cost: 93, p: 0 }, 
  lat       : { cost: 33, p: 0 }
}; 
const H_VALUES = [0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 22, 24, 25, 26, 28, 30]; 

var $d = document, 
    frmEl, hvEl, rsltEl; 

$d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  frmEl  = $d.forms.calc; 
  hvEl   = $d.getElementById('hv'); 
  rsltEl = $d.getElementById('result'); 
  frmEl.h.addEventListener('input', function () {
    hvEl.textContent = H_VALUES[this.value]; 
  }); 
  let ctrls = $d.querySelectorAll('#calc select, #calc input'); 
  for (let ctrl of ctrls)
    ctrl.addEventListener('input', calculate); 
  calculate(); 
});

function calculate() {
  let mt = MATERIALS[frmEl.material.value]; 
  if (!mt) {
    rsltEl.textContent = 'Нет данных о материале';
    return; 
  }
  let w = frmEl.w.value, 
      h = +hvEl.textContent, 
      cutPrice = frmEl.price.value;
  // типа формула подсчета
  let result = w * h / 1000 * cutPrice; 
  rsltEl.textContent = (result.toFixed(2) + '₽').replace('.', ','); 
}
```

```css
* { font: 16px sans-serif; }
body { width: 450px; }

#calc     { line-height: 2.0em; }
#material { width: 320px; }

input {
  vertical-align: middle; 
  width: 200px; 
}
```

```html
<form id="calc" name="calc">
  Материал: <select id="material" name="material">
    <option value="steelblack">Чёрная сталь</option>
    <option value="med">Медь</option>
    <option value="titan">Титан</option>
    <option value="lat">Латунь</option>
    <option value="palych">Василий Палыч</option>
  </select><br>
  Укажите толщину (мм): <input type="range" name="h" id="h" max="22" value="0"><span id="hv">0.5</span><br>
  Укажите длину реза (мм): <input type="text" name="w" id="w" value="1000"><br>
  Цена резки: <input type="number" name="price" min="0" value="23.2">
  <hr>
  <span id="result"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Выше вот писал комментарий: как же как я понимаю у вас расчёт идёт из cost, а мне нужно чтобы расчёт производился совершенно с другого блока, допустим сделать переменную var cutprice и туда case sb0.5 = 12; sb0.7 = 16, то есть нужно чтобы был определён какой метал выбран и какая толщина и исходя из этих данный с другого места бралась цена для расчёта стоимости резки

Comment: @st1mset, _«мне нужно чтобы расчёт производился совершенно с другого блока»_ - этого не было в вопросе. Приведите ваш вопрос в более понятную форму: что имеется; что необходимо; какие трудности возникли - в четком и последовательном виде.

Comment: так я вроде обновил вопрос, или этой информации не достаточно?

Comment: Сейчас отсутствует HTML как минимум некоторых эл-тов (а то что есть, разбросано по тексту), нет формулы расчета,  и т.д.. Прочтя комменты, вижу что на все ваши вопросы уже отвечено, и если надеетесь плюсом получить готовое решение под свои условия - пожалуйста, прикрепите работающий (тут, а не где-то еще) краткий пример кода с _последовательным и емким_ описанием задачи его "допила" до желаемого. Это повысит шансы. Вы же не думаете что кому-то интересно возиться с "заказами", внося правку за правкой?..

Comment: Относительно того как получить значение цены из блока, в общих чертах: выбираете элемент блока из DOM; затем через свойство `textContent` получаете текстовое содержимое; (опционально - выполняете поиск подстроки); и приводите значение к числовому типу, например как `+varName`. Остальные значения для подсчета - в примере они и так берутся из элементов страницы.

Comment: подправил, надеюсь теперь более ярко отобразил, я не прошу допилить мне код чтобы всё работало, я прошу как то объяснить и направить меня в нужное направление чтобы до моего гуманитарного ума дошло куда что и как :)

Comment: До сих пор не понимаю насчет этого "другого места", из которого берется стоимость резки (в зависимости от металла и толщины). Получается, спрашиваете «как мне достать данные откуда-нибудь?» поймите, что на этот _общий_ вопрос невозможно дать _конкретный_ ответ. Конкретизируйте то место: чем оно является (если это элемент, то какой именно), и в каком виде данные (их формат, и/или пример). Еще, поможет уточнение, что именно непонятно в примере кода - ведь там значения достаются и из `input`, и из `span`, и из `select`...

Comment: в данный момент мне не понятно как заставить код считать какой материал выбран и какая указана толщина, а потом исходя из этих данных как заставить всё это дело взять данные из другого масива и сделать расчёт стоимости реза

Comment: **1.** Получение материала выбранного в select, и толщины: **1a.** выбираем из DOM элемент содержащий значение (есть много способов); **1b.** обращаемся к свойству эл-та value (через точку: `v = element.value;`). **2.** Как взять данные из другого массива: есть сотни, если не тысячи, вариантов кода который это делает - все зависит от структуры данных в массиве, и желаемой структуры+формата выходных данных. **3.** Расчет стоимости реза: вот это уже надо уточнить у тех, кто занимается расчетами в фирме по резке металла (я формул не знаю, хз как толщина и сплав влияют на произведение цена*длина).